# How to bind data attribute instead of id?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

Use bootstrap 3 carousel - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxv1osq0/)

```css
/* for testing only */

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div data-id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel) uses the `id` for the `carousel`

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Carousel Indicators -->
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>

<!-- Carousel Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
```

I would like to use instead of `id` the `data attribute(data-id)`

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div data-id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

If you use the data attribute - then pagination and navigation does not work

How to bind the data attribute to the pagination and navigation of the slider?

Thank you

I will be glad to any help

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use data-id rather than id? It is most likely defined somewhere in the imported JS code, `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">`. And just for the record, why do you keep referring to some _date_ attributes, when all we see are _data_ attributes?

Comment: @eli Thank you. Corrected the question

Comment: To expand on my comment, you'd probably want to find the non-minified/uglified version of that js code, and then replace all references to the id with something like `dataset.id` (`dataset` will contain any "custom" attribute you define in your tags, so `data-id` will be reachable with `dataset.id` in JS). This is rather time consuming, hence the question _why_ you'd want to replace `id` with `data-id`.

Comment: I use owl carousel 2 sync, inside of which is used bootstrap slider. Due to the fact that owl-carousel makes clones of slides, the bootstrap carousel does not work correctly (dubbed id)